# Use PHP and Bootstrap to make a column of content for ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns, advanced-custom-fields

Before I decided to post, I read all I could on this site with people of the same issues. Nothing seemed to work... I will explain it the best I can, I am using ACF + Repeater add-on to make A Restaurant Menu. I have Bootstrap loaded to help with making things easier, I want to have 3 columns going across. This is the HTML and PHP side of things.. I am using Bridge Theme, so I had to change the Bootstrap container class to container-acf because it kept going to the Bridge style instead. My end Goal if for it  [Look Similar To This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTc00.jpg)   All help is appreciated Thanks

My guess is I will need a Foreach loop.

```
`<?php 
/*
Template Name: Restaurant Menu Template 
 */
get_header(); ?>
<div class="content-fill-in-menu">HERE</div>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">

        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <header class="entry-header">
                <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content wpb_wrapper container-acf">


            <?php if ( have_rows('menu_sections') ):
                while ( have_rows('menu_sections') ): the_row(); ?>

                    <h2 class="section_desc"><?php the_sub_field('section_title'); ?></h2>

                    <?php if ( have_rows('section_items') ): ?>

                        <?php while ( have_rows('section_items') ): the_row(); ?>
                    <article class="lmenu">
                        <ul>
                    <li>
                    <div class="container-acf">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 item_info">

                                <img class="dish_pic" src="<?php the_sub_field('dish_pic'); ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('dish_name'); ?>">
                                <h3 class="item_name"><?php the_sub_field('dish_name'); ?></h3>
                                <p class="item_desc"><?php the_sub_field('dish_description'); ?></p>
                                <h4 class="price">$<?php the_sub_field('dish_price'); ?></h4>
                                <span class="separator"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </article>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        </table>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endwhile;
            endif; ?>


            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        </article><!-- #post-## -->



        <?php endwhile; // End the loop. ?>

        </main><!-- .site-main -->

    </div><!-- .content-area -->
    <div class="content-fill-in-menu">HERE</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of your problems are in the loop into "section_items" repeater field.
In the "while" loop, you open and close a container and a row for each item, so you don't have your render in columns.

Here in a idea of changes, you need open a row before the start of the loop. I put a counter ($i) to restart a row each 4 items to prevent problems :

```
    <?php if ( have_rows('menu_sections') ): ?>
      <?php while ( have_rows('menu_sections') ): the_row(); ?>

        <h2 class="section_desc"><?php the_sub_field('section_title'); ?></h2>
        <?php if ( have_rows('section_items') ): ?>

          <?php $i = 1; ?>
          <div class="row">

            <?php while ( have_rows('section_items') ): the_row(); ?>
              <div class="col-md-3 item_info">
                <article class="lmenu">
                  <img class="dish_pic" src="<?php the_sub_field('dish_pic'); ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('dish_name'); ?>">
                  <h3 class="item_name"><?php the_sub_field('dish_name'); ?></h3>
                  <p class="item_desc"><?php the_sub_field('dish_description'); ?></p>
                  <h4 class="price">$<?php the_sub_field('dish_price'); ?></h4>
                  <span class="separator"></span>
                </article>
              </div><!-- /.col -->

              <?php
              if( $i == 4 ){
                echo '</div><div class="row">';
                $i = 0;
              }
              $i++;
              ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

          </div><!-- /.row -->

        <?php endif; ?>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try and report back... Appreciate the help

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try and report back... Appreciate the help